# Serialization Versus Encoding

Tags: c#, wcf, serialization

What is the different between Serialization and Encoding.

As i understood

**"Serialization defines how the .NET object maps to XML, while Encoding defines how the XML is written out to a stream of bytes. "**

is this correct ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. **Serialization** used for transmission of messages in between client and server we need to convert CLR types to standards-based XML.

WCF defines serialization as the process of converting an object graph into an XML Information Set (XML Infoset)

```
1. The XML Infoset is the data model WCF uses internally to represent a message.
2. The XML Infoset is the data model for representing an XML document.
```

**Encoding** used to describe the process of converting a WCF message into an array of bytes. This is done so that the message can be sent across a transport protocol.

Here is the good explanation with example http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163569.aspx#S1

Comment: I realise you posted this a long time ago, but if you're still around, it would be great if you could expand the acronyms the first time you use them.

Answer (score 3):

`Serialization` is the conversion of the in-memory .NET object to another format such as `XML`, `JSON`, etc. so that they can be stored or transmitted. This format is usually text i.e. a string of characters.

`Encoding` is the conversion of these characters to a byte stream to transmit them over the wire or store them to disk. Some common encodings are `ASCII`, `UTF-8`, etc.

From Wikipedia,

[Serialization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization): Serialization is the process of translating **data structures** or **object state** into a format that can be stored (for example, in a file or memory buffer, or transmitted across a network connection link) and reconstructed later in the same or another computer environment.

[Character Encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encoding): A character encoding system consists of a code that pairs each **character** from a given repertoire with something else — such as a **bit pattern** ... to facilitate the transmission of data (generally numbers or text) through telecommunication networks or for data storage.